# Cannot Open/Close Drawer Layout react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

Im trying to use for my first time the Drawer Layout from react-native-gesture-handler, but everytime i try to use it wont open.

Im getting this error(both in the openDrawer):

[image]

```
const newBet: React.FC = () => {
  let drawer: any = null;

  var renderDrawer = () => {
    return (
      <Button onPress={drawer.closeDrawer()} title='Close Drawer'></Button>
    );
  };
  var render = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <DrawerLayout
          ref={(refDrawer) => {
            refDrawer = refDrawer;
          }}
          drawerWidth={200}
          drawerPosition='right'
          drawerType='front'
          drawerBackgroundColor='#ddd'
          renderNavigationView={renderDrawer}
        >
          <Button onPress={drawer.openDrawer} title='Open Drawer'></Button>
        </DrawerLayout>
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <Text onPress={drawer.openDrawer()}>Render Drawer Layout</Text>)
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default newBet;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `drawer` to `null`, and never assign a value to it. You have a typo in `ref={}`:

```
ref={(refDrawer) => {
   // refDrawer = refDrawer; Assigning value to itself here :)
   drawer = refDrawer 
}}
```

Also, I'm not sure since I didn't check this but I think `ref={drawer}` also works.

Next, note how you sometimes write

```
onPress={drawer.closeDrawer()} // ending with '()'
// vs
onPress={drawer.openDrawer} // ending without '()'
```

You can't directly call a function or it will execute it immediately. So either write:

```
onPress={drawer.closeDrawer}
// or
onPress={() => drawer.closeDrawer()}
```

That should do the trick hopefully!