# Cannot Open DrawerLayout of react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: react-native

Im trying to use for my first time the Drawer Layout from react-native-gesture-handler, but everytime i try to use it wont open.

No error messages, nothing happens.

Simply my code as following :

```js
function Detail({ route, navigation }) {
  let draw = React.useRef<DrawerLayout>();

  function renderSearch() {
    return (<View style={styles.drawerContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.drawerText}>I am in the drawer!</Text>
    </View>)
  }

  const handleDrawerSlide = (status) => {
    // outputs a value between 0 and 1
    console.log(status);
  };

  return (
      <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>

      <View style={{}}>
        <DrawerLayout
          ref={(drawer) => {
            draw.current = drawer;
          }}
          drawerWidth={300}
          drawerPosition={DrawerLayout.positions.Left}
          drawerType="front"
          drawerBackgroundColor="#ddd"
          renderNavigationView={renderSearch}
          onDrawerSlide={handleDrawerSlide}>

        </DrawerLayout>
        <View style={{ height: 200, marginTop: 100 }}>
          <RectButton onPress={draw.current.openDrawer}>
            <Text>Open drawer</Text>
          </RectButton>
         </View>
        </View>
     </GestureHandlerRootView>
  )

}
```

I had checked this question and no helpful. the `draw.current` exist if I log it in console.

[Cannot Open/Close Drawer Layout react-native-gesture-handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69469089/cannot-open-close-drawer-layout-react-native-gesture-handler)

I tried change
`onPress={draw.current.openDrawer}`
to
`onPress={() => {draw.current.openDrawer();console.log(draw.current.state) }}`

Got output:

```json
{"containerWidth": 430, "dragX": 0, "drawerOpened": true, "drawerState": "Idle", "drawerTranslation": 300, "touchX": 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout official [example](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/blob/main/example/src/basic/horizontalDrawer/index.tsx):

```js
        <DrawerLayout
          ref={(_drawer) => {
            draw.current = _drawer; // Rename parameter
          }}
          drawerWidth={300}
          drawerPosition={DrawerLayout.positions.Left}
          drawerType="front"
          drawerBackgroundColor="#ddd"
          renderNavigationView={renderSearch}
          onDrawerSlide={handleDrawerSlide}>

        </DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Yes. I was following the official example and facing this issue . I had tried your solution to rename parameter but still not get lucky....

Comment: Interesting use ```Pressable```instead of ```RectButton```worked for me.

Comment: I tried `Pressable` and got no lucy, I give up. Still great appreciative of your help .